# Autogenerated column from counting in a different table (based on a set of conditions)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create an autogenerated column that's contingent upon a query from another table (table2).

```
xid | status | time
-----------------------
1     2         2021-03-03 04:00:00
2     0         2021-02-27 13:00:00
1     2         2021-03-02 23:00:00
1     1         2021-03-01 01:00:00
```

From table2, I want to autogenerate the following column "calculated" in table1

```
id | calculated
-----------------------
1     2       
2     0
```

If I were to write this as a query it'd look as follows

```
SELECT 
      id
    , COUNT(*)
FROM
      table2
WHERE
      status=2 AND time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
GROUP BY
      id;
```

except I want this counted number to be autogenerated in table1. Is this possible?

I was planning to use GENERATE ALWAYS AS () STORED, but from reading up on the documentation it seems that this only works with values in columns from the same table? If so, does anyone know a different way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is a [*materialized view*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html):

```
create materialized view mv_table2_summary as
    SELECT id, COUNT(*)
    FROM table2
    WHERE status = 2 AND time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    GROUP BY id;
```

You can schedule a job to periodically update it.